# How do I get Lydia to stop attacking people so I can progress in the quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm at the first quest in College of Winterhold and I came in with Lydia. Tolfdir wanted me to demonstrate the Ward spell but Lydia was in the middle and not moving at all and the quest wouldn't progress even though I used the spell. So I told her to stop following but suddenly she started attacking Tolfdir and everyone was attacking. Since she goes to a tired state, it became a loop where she would fight after getting up over and over again...

I love Lydia as a faithful housecarl and so I don't wanna kill her... So what should I do?

**Info:** I don't use any mods and only have the add-ons (Dawnguard and so on)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skyrim can be a buggy game.

You already recognized the problem, so it is best to just go along with the game and help it a little bit out.

Simply send Lydia home and do this part without her. She will be waiting in your house or in the hall of the jarl in Whiterun.

Sending your companion home will not teleport them out of the room and home instantly. Instead they will stop following your movement and will walk towards the exit. This can take some time and they will still engage in combat situations in this state. Go to another room send them home, maybe fast travel real quick to let some time pass and come back. They should be gone then.

Comment: It's the sending part which resulted in the huge fight... I better load my last save and send her away before she enters the college...

Comment: You mean sending her home causes a fight? That's not what I got from your question at all. Can you not just walk outside again?

Comment: Oh and sending her home won't teleport her instantly out of the room. I will edit this in.

Comment: +1 for the another room tip, she went without a fuss! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you've already fought against  Whiterun in the Stormcloak-Imperial war, then you you have two choices: have her wait outside or kill her.
Otherwise, you could just ask her to go home.